# Blurred custom tiles on Android Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap, google-maps-api-2

I want to show a CustomOverlay on a Google Maps V2. The loading of the tiles works as expected, the only thing is, that the shown tiles are not appearing to be sharp at all, kind of blurry. Google did not get me to an usable answer.

I took the approach of adding classical 256px x 256px tiles for the TileProvider. I managed to get a tile source where the images were @2x (retina), which made the whole visual experience much sharper, but I would rather not use this source, as the data transfer rate is four times higher, hence not usable on mobile devices and slow internet speeds.

I included two different examples (screenshots) of the rendered map, both with the same configuration (OSM - 256x256 tiles) and with the provided TileProviderOsm. One is on a Galaxy Nexus and the other on a Nexus 5 phone. Both do not look like they were rendered correctly.

Any idea what I could do to prevent the blurriness or increase the sharpness?

My TileProvider looks like following:

```
 public class TileProviderOsm extends UrlTileProvider {

    private static final String MAP_URL = "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/%d/%d/%d.png";

    private static int TILE_WIDTH  = 256;
    private static int TILE_HEIGHT = 256;

    public static int MIN_ZOOM = 7;
    public static int MAX_ZOOM = 15;

    public TileProviderOsm() {
        super(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {

        String s = String.format(Locale.US, MAP_URL, zoom, x, y);
        URL url = null;
        try {
             url = new URL(s);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return url;
    }
 }
```

Here's how I add the overlay to the map:

```
 map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(new TileProviderOsm()));
```

Here are some examples of the rendered Google Map:

[image: Google Maps V2 on a Nexus 5 - OSM Map tiles look blurry]
[image: Google Maps V2 on a Galaxy Nexu - OSM Map tiles look blurry]

Comment: Do you resolve this issue? I stumbled with the same problem it really annoying that all maps with tiles 256*256 displaying in such quality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a problem with the zoom level and scaling of the map tiles. This seems to be a problem with the Maps API V2 for Android. The behavior is supposedly intended as stated here: [gmaps-api-issues #4840](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4840)

I solved it by requesting larger tiles from the WMS - just replace 256x256 with 512x512.

Comment: Not only do the 512x512 tiles look sharper on HDPI devices, they may contain more map features than the 256x256 tiles.  This is the case with the USGS National Map topo base map.  But I'm not convinced that issue #4840 is entirely due to scaling.  I've seen Google Maps v2 show a blurry map even with 512x512 tiles.  Zooming out and back in sometimes fixes it.  It may have something to do with the zoom controls.  Maybe you sometimes end up at e.g. zoom 3.1 instead of zoom 3, looking at tiles from zoom 4.  Just a hunch.

Comment: I agree with you @pegel, so I mark your answer as solved. I also managed to include 512x512 tiles and the situation improved, but as Kevin mentioned, the problem is not completely gone. I have had the same observations as Kevin with non integer zoom levels, so blurred tiles are shown because of an apparently improper rendering at non integer zoom levels.

Comment: Thank's! Helped me a lot.. but as mentioned above.. the problem is still there, but at least it looks a lot better.

Answer (score 11):

I am solving this issue by drawing four tiles into one tile.

I wrote this TileProvider which is using another tile provider to create higher resolution tiles.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Tile;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileProvider;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class CanvasTileProvider implements TileProvider {

    static final int TILE_SIZE = 512;
    private TileProvider mTileProvider;

    public CanvasTileProvider(TileProvider tileProvider) {
        mTileProvider = tileProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        byte[] data;
        Bitmap image = getNewBitmap();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
        boolean isOk = onDraw(canvas, zoom, x, y);
        data = bitmapToByteArray(image);
        image.recycle();

        if (isOk) {
            Tile tile = new Tile(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, data);
            return tile;
        } else {
            return mTileProvider.getTile(x, y, zoom);
        }
    }

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    private boolean onDraw(Canvas canvas, int zoom, int x, int y) {
        x = x * 2;
        y = y * 2;
        Tile leftTop = mTileProvider.getTile(x, y, zoom + 1);
        Tile leftBottom = mTileProvider.getTile(x, y + 1, zoom + 1);
        Tile rightTop = mTileProvider.getTile(x + 1, y, zoom + 1);
        Tile rightBottom = mTileProvider.getTile(x + 1, y + 1, zoom + 1);

        if (leftTop == NO_TILE && leftBottom == NO_TILE && rightTop == NO_TILE && rightBottom == NO_TILE) {
            return false;
        }


        Bitmap bitmap;

        if (leftTop != NO_TILE) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(leftTop.data, 0, leftTop.data.length);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
            bitmap.recycle();
        }

        if (leftBottom != NO_TILE) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(leftBottom.data, 0, leftBottom.data.length);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 256, paint);
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
        if (rightTop != NO_TILE) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rightTop.data, 0, rightTop.data.length);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 256, 0, paint);
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
        if (rightBottom != NO_TILE) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rightBottom.data, 0, rightBottom.data.length);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 256, 256, paint);
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private Bitmap getNewBitmap() {
        Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        image.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        return image;
    }

    private static byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bm) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
        try {
            bos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```